# Are there any names of food that are associated with political correctness other than Fried chicken?

Tags: word-usage

The word Spanish golfer, Sergio Garcia used in answering a reporter’s question about the status of his current relationship with his rival, Tiger Woods on May 21st – “We’ll have him ‘round every night. We will serve fried chicken,” was bitterly criticized as an offensive and retrograding remark by media and most of audience, and he apologized.

This reminds me of the classic episode that Japanese Prime Minister, Hayato Ikeda made a slip of tongue in the Diet on December 7, 1950, and was forced to resign by saying “The poor are better to eat barley-mixed rice,” in reference to the administration's austerity policy.

But this blunder wasn't about the race, but was about the class. Until post WW II, barley-mixed rice had been considered as the poor’s staple in our country.

Are there any other foods that carry political correct implications that non-native English speakers should be mindful in speaking / writing English than fried chicken?

Comment: Not really what you're looking for but there is all the [rank idiocy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_fries) associated with renaming _Frech fries_ to _freedom fries_.

Comment: Watermelon has pretty much the exact connotation as fried chicken.

Comment: Good question, Yoichi, and a reminder that we have myriad, creative ways to insult each other by race, nationality, ethnicity, urbaneness, education, sophistication, age and infirmity.  To anchor this list, an interesting point is that even motorcycles are fodder for discrimination . . . Japanese motorcycles are referred to as "rice burners" by some Harley-Davidson riders. (Who also get categorized as "having nothing to protect" to account for the number of helmetless H-D riders that sport a colorful bandana on their heads instead.) No stereotype is 100% accurate and most are just mean.

Comment: [Corn pone](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cornpone) and [grits](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grits) probably carry far more negative associations to the average Brit. We know what *fried chicken* actually is (plenty of us *eat* it, obviously). But all we know about *corn pone* and *grits* is that they're associated with the American Deep South (so by a variation on **Munch** hausen's Syndrome by Proxy, they're foodstuffs associated with racism! :)

Comment: Other foods traditionally associated with black people in the U.S. South are collard greens, fatback, and chitlins (or chitterlings—hog intestines). Black-eyed peas, grits, and molasses are less race-identified, but all are definitely Southern and (perhaps more to the point) widely considered poor folks' food.

Comment: To EL&U moderators and users: Related with this question, I keep receiving 2 down votes (or close votes) regularly on almost of every my question as soon as, at least within a quarter minutes after posting it these days. It doesn't seem to be a coincidence, because it never happened before, at least by the end of last year. Isn’t it strange? Is my question so stupid? Isn’t there any way to identify who’s doing this?

Comment: The poor folks' foods I mentioned above remind me of a scene in _The Seven Samurai_, where destitute farmers try to entice ronin samurai to protect their village by offering them rice balls, while the farmers themselves eat millet. Millet would seem to have had a status in Japan in those days comparable to collard greens and chitlins in the U.S. South today: No one who could afford something better would choose to eat it.

Comment: Many stereotypical "Black" foods were simply Southern poor folks' foods until the Great Migration brought millions of Black people north, taking their eating habits with them.  And thus, White Yankees made the association between fried chicken and Black people.

Comment: @YoichiOishi: That is really strange! I thought everybody liked your questions (I do). I wonder whether this happens to other people too. Since when has this been going on?

Comment: Cerberus. Constant down / close votes by two persons (definitely one person) became prominent coming into this year. Taking examples of the most recent questions of mine by tracking back Reputation on my page, I got 2 down votes, 2 down votes, 2 close votes, 2close votes, 2close votes, 1 close vote in a row on the latest 6 questions - You can track this record. This never happened before (at least by the end of the last year since I joined this site. I was patient thus far. But now enough is enough. I think it’s the time to bring the matter on open table.

Comment: Cont. I wrote as follows to a ‘suspect’ guy as the additional comment in my question the day before yesterday: without any answer.
By the way you look particularly interested in my questions. Can’t you tell me why you care my question so much, notwithstanding scores of new questions come into the site every day? Are you a fan of my questions, or a maniac who likes to keep casting down / close vote no later than an innocent user posts a question? I’m curious. I think your constant and habitual down / close voting practice is unfair and egregiously mean.

Comment: *Fried chicken* is **not** any more politically incorrect than *boiled-egg* or *potato* unless used in a context with offensive connotations.

Comment: Kris. Commmon. If Fried chicken isn't so politically incorrect, why the world / press are making a fuss? Why should Garcia have apologized to Woods? Beside, You haven't answered to my above question I gave you on May 27. Please don't stalk around my question.

Comment: Kris. Cont. Regardless your maniacly habitual down / close voting effort, again this time, this question won 8 up votes already. Your degrading efforts don't work so long.

Comment: Yoichi Oishi, I enjoy your sincere and thought-provoking questions even when I don't try to answer them, and I understand your being upset at receiving frequent down votes. But I think it's wiser not to get caught up in bad feelings about them. Some regular users of this site have a narrower view of the proper scope of the site than others do, and some of them frequently cast negative votes in support of their vision of what the site should be. To me, the anonymous up/down voting aspect of this site is its least appealing feature. I hope you won't let it deter you from asking good questions.

Comment: Sven Yargs. Thanks. It's true. There are ups and downs in the life. There are good guys and bad guys, wise guys and stupid guys, flexible guys and pathologically square guys, and fair guys and mean guys equally in the world. Let’s leave it what ‘he’ does. Que sera sera.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The remark Garcia made was criticized specifically as being racist, because Tiger Woods is a black man and fried chicken is stereotypically associated with blacks/African Americans. There's tons of potentially offensive food/racial combinations like this, and it really depends on what race you're talking about. These may be specific to the US.

- African Americans: Fried chicken, watermelon, fruit-flavored sodas/beverages like Kool-aid or orange soda
- Hispanics/Latinos: Beans, Tex-Mex food like tacos/nachos/burritos
- Asians (of any nationality): Chop Suey, Dog/cat meat
- Native Americans: Alcohol, particularly whiskey.

There's lots more stereotypical foods that you could list, depending on nationality. It's just that the ethnic groups being stereotyped aren't subject to as much racism as the first few I listed so they aren't considered to be as offensive, although they are still kind of rude. A few more examples:

- French: Frog Legs, Cheese
- Irish: Potatoes, Alcohol
- Canadians: Various northern animals like Moose or Beaver
- Germans: Sausage, Sauerkraut

Comment: As to Native Americans and whiskey, a particularly careful bigot will use the word "firewater", to make sure you get the point.

Comment: I'll just like to confirm the answerer's comment about many of the food/racial combinations being US-specific. As a Brit, I didn't understand the quotation in the original questions, and the only ones quoted in the above answer that I recognise are the French, Irish & German ones.

Comment: The phrase is politically incorrect only when used in a context where it could be so construed as being offensive. The media and some in the audience heckled over a non-issue.

Comment: Canada: Doughnuts, specifically, jelly filled

Comment: I would recommended adding "Rice" to the Asian stereotype list -- I've actually seen that more often than the two you listed.

Comment: Add "sushi" to the list. A friend of mine was slapped with a discrimination suit for calling a Korean-American subordinate "sushi."

Answer (score 11):

It is not the *name* of a food that necessarily causes problems, but the **association of some characteristic** or activity with some group **in a way that marginalizes** them.

In some cases, affinity for certain foods is part of a negative stereotype. In 2008, Fuzzy Zoeller made rather ill-received comments about Tiger Woods choosing fried chicken and collard greens for the Masters Champion Dinner; these foods, along with watermelon, corn bread, and others were long used in racist iconography, owing to a supposed predilection for them among African-Americans. The derogatory term *beaner* similarly refers to the presence of pinto beans in the Mexican diet, and the old-fashioned slur *mackerel snapper* refers to the old Catholic practice of eating fish on Fridays.

But one needn't refer to a comprehensively developed stereotype to offend. **To reduce any group of people to a single trait is inherently problematic.** If you call the French team *beret-wearers*, you are clearly trying to stir up animosity against them— even though not only is there nothing wrong with wearing berets, but there's no evidence that the French wear them any more often than people of any other nationality. It's simply a cheap association because the word *beret* is French in origin and pronunciation.

Answer (score 10):

In the UK, we sometimes, politically-incorrectly, refer to French people as "Frogs", because they eat frogs' legs. (They in turn refer to us as "les rosbifs", or "Roast Beefs").

The US refer to us as "Limeys" because our sailors used to eat limes (the idiom "limey bastard" is still very much in use).

There are also a lot of jokes about Latvians and potatoes.

Other than that, there are a lot of words which are used to describe people, bodily parts, acts, etc. with sexual connotations, including [crumpet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crumpet#Slang_usage), [cherry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_%28disambiguation%29#Slang), [pork](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pork), [nuts](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=nuts).

Also be careful of mentioning any kind of sausage, including bologna, salami, hotdogs and particularly wieners.

Comment: According to the Latvian citizen that I share an office with, this association is confusing Latvia with Lithuania. In Lithuania, the majority of traditional dishes are made with potatoes. This is not so in Latvia.

Comment: Right, and African Americans don't actually all eat fried chicken. But people do make jokes and comments which are politically incorrect about different countries / cultures / races and their food, and they also make jokes about Latvians and potatoes. Go figure. 
http://www.reddit.com/r/latvianjokes     http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/latvian%20jokes     http://www.sadanduseless.com/2012/12/latvian-jokes/

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger. It is a useful and relevant addition.

Comment: Shooting was never intended; sorry if I wrote it in a way that came across that way. I would consider it a limitation of small, written comment format than any malice on my part :) I think I responded that way because you said "this association is confusing Latvia with Lithuania." Associations don't confuse anything - people do - and I hadn't confused any association at all.

Comment: The semantic error was mine!

Comment: "Limeys" hasn't been used in the US for decades that I know of. In fact the last time I can recall seeing a reference to it was in a history book on the War of 1812...

Comment: @ryan Search for "limey bastard" or "limey bastard quote" - still very much in use in that idiom.

Comment: @Lunivore huh, it's funny that you would mention that, because I have heard that idiom, just used by a Brit, not an American.

Comment: @ryan They possibly aren't aware that Americans normally use it for Brits ;)

Answer (score 5):

As Marcus_33 points out, the most problematic instances in which someone refers to a particular food to disparage someone else involve foods associated with particular racial ethnic groups. Four U.S. epithets that specifically equate groups of people with a particular food are *Beaner* (Mexican/Latino), *Frog* (French), *Kraut* (German), and *Limey* (British). All are objectionable and well worth avoiding. Weirdly enough, the term *Ricer* arose in the United States about 10 or 15 years ago to refer to people who modify and customize automobiles from Asian countries to make them especially fast and powerful. I wouldn't use that term either.

In addition, foods sometimes come up in the service of political criticism. According to Robert Jewett, in *Captain America and the Crusade Against Evil* (2003),

> A Republican media consultant suggested that, in the 1984 election, "it's the perfect gentleman versus the cowboy. ... Reagan is a healthy dose of macho, and Mondale is part of the Brie-and-chablis crowd."

This food-centric criticism caught on as a cultural critique, and for some years afterward, "brie and chablis" became a shorthand for the tastes of affluent (and depending on your political biases, effete) U.S. liberals, in contradistinction to an appetite for meat and potatoes (and perhaps Budweiser beer) that presumably marks one as a heartland American.

Comment: *Ricer* is derived from *Rice Burner*, a (potentially deragatory) term for the cars themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Some North Africans and middle-easterners also get food-stereotyped. The Egyptians are often referred to as broad beans, Algerians as couscous, Algerian Kabylians as olive oil,  Tunisians as harissa (a kind of hot sauce) and the Syrians as falafel or shawarma.

Comment: But are these politically incorrect? I wouldn't take offense at being called a hamburger-eating American. Do Syrians take offense at being called falafel eaters?

Comment: I guess you'd take offense if your country is referred to as the United States of Hamburgers.So would the Syrians or the Turkish if they get referred to as the Kebab or Shawarma republics. It's all in the intent

Answer (score 0):

Well, Bush administration types angry at the French refusal to participate in the 2003 invasion of Iraq, referred to them as "cheese-eating surrender monkeys." (They really meant "quiche-eating" but that presumably sounded too elitist.) And in a kind of reverse food-stereotyping, we were all supposed to refer to French fries as "freedom fries." Ah, the good old days!...

Comment: "Cheese-eating surrender monkeys" is a line from [a 1995 episode of *The Simpsons*](http://www.snpp.com/episodes/2F32.html), and popularized not by the administration but Jonah Goldberg, a columnist.

Comment: @choster: Quiet, you! We can't let silly things like facts get in the way of blaming Bush!